# Axis limits causing error when attempting to save figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a problem with saving figures with matplotlib and the `pgf-backend`.
If I have a plot in which the axis limits (e.g. `X`: `[20,70]`; `Y`: `[0,-50]`) are much lower than the datapoints with the highest `X`- and `Y`-values (lowest datapoint: `[0,0]`; highest datapoint: `[150000,-200000]`) there's always the following error:

```
File "<>", line 816, in exportGraphs2

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig

return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1421, in savefig

self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure

**kwargs)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pgf.py", line 882, in print_pdf

self._print_pdf_to_fh(fh, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pgf.py", line 858, in _print_pdf_to_fh

check_output(cmdargs, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, cwd=tmpdir)

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\compat\subprocess.py", line 69, in _check_output

raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)

TypeError
: 
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output'
```

**However**, if the axis limits are larger or slightly smaller than the largest values of the datapoints everything works fine.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

**Edit:**
Here is a part of my code. Since it's quite complex due to reading data from QTIPlot it's just a short snippet.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import sys

sys.path.append("..")
mpl.use('pgf')
latex_preamble = {"text.usetex": True,
                  "pgf.rcfonts": False,
                  "pgf.preamble": [r"\usepackage{cmbright}",
                                   r"\usepackage{siunitx}",
                                   r"\usepackage{fontspec}",
                                   r"\setmainfont{Calibri}",
                                   r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",
                                   r"\usepackage{textgreek}"]}
mpl.rcParams.update(latex_preamble)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 24})

x = [186691.98079420399, 94747.037718184903, 43238.854190494698, 19067.6709222838, 8804.8960840724703, 4616.3273881164196, 2784.39307777148, 1924.44569810138, 1421.6244001381001, 1044.0988528353901, 738.32026028954704, 499.78345554987698, 325.91902800532, 208.07599600125701, 136.48397798235101, 97.188999849599597, 77.189874321047498, 66.814364230185305, 61.930218121218097, 58.897007608510897, 57.004014967900098, 55.406903357827098, 54.041568494235101, 52.802043730081699, 51.759023715688997, 50.777510655714799, 49.815484593681198, 48.961058456802903, 48.191611656054903, 47.4882902162026, 46.848714837688902, 46.190288085990197, 45.3774348340838, 44.4693505256935, 43.434754403205901, 42.220754480990998, 40.854413497723201, 39.357546952524302, 37.878908712040399, 36.491255819384499, 35.284755433638502, 34.2610953105862, 33.420298363499299, 32.766550165311301, 32.298722787726398, 31.9724893134679, 31.733745041689001, 31.560804411243499, 31.4680666775029]  

y = [-225457.06785031699, -151654.317412915, -93620.558383412499, -53880.168115145199, -30116.624926982, -16905.4587130902, -9712.6193383353802, -5810.69026270625, -3678.9706880631902, -2475.8794835536701, -1751.8371788254599, -1253.7787633139801, -901.12220338703003, -643.67630154638596, -454.56954062206199, -318.51086928594498, -223.35257106637999, -156.97451642102101, -112.89935316650001, -82.655897872917393, -61.638224025861199, -46.766272864377299, -36.093957934023599, -28.313379974280299, -22.4321281711178, -17.961980555220599, -14.556781594439601, -11.97682273137, -10.061208825108, -8.6707057874908102, -7.6773295770935901, -7.0721051618041599, -6.7628705905120299, -6.6605343376401303, -6.69407747810377, -6.8113923612978997, -6.8702914807042204, -6.8388590566887899, -6.5692275645203999, -6.1065237236783396, -5.5035760007258503, -4.79953162532468, -4.0671542575787001, -3.3690652676737902, -2.7612664707248298, -2.2359507233406499, -1.77482078896039, -1.44286837047643, -1.1560624817337399]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
p, = ax1.plot(x, y)        # really, x and y would be arrays of doubles which are read from QTIPlot

ax1.set_xlabel(unicode("Z'"))
ax1.set_ylabel(unicode("Z''"))

ax1.set_xlim(20,70)
ax1.set_ylim(0,-50)
ax1.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

ax1.tick_params(axis='y', direction = 'out')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', direction = 'out')
ax1.yaxis.tick_left()
ax1.xaxis.tick_bottom()

plt.savefig("figure.pdf")
```

Comment: Please post your code to some site. We'll try to help

Comment: I just added some code

Comment: To me it seems that the issues arise from the `pgf` backend. Can you run [this example](https://github.com/pwuertz/matplotlib-backend-pgf/blob/master/examples/test_fontspec.py) without error? If not, [the documentation](https://github.com/pwuertz/matplotlib-backend-pgf) states that `The only requirement is an installed TeX distribution that includes xelatex and the pgf package (both found in TeX Live for example). The xelatex command must be in the system's path.` - if you type `which xelatex` what do you get?

Comment: I do have a windows computer so `which xelatex` doesn't work. In general the export works. It just doesn't work if the axis limits are much smaller than the x and/or y value of the highest datapoints.